# how do i prove the existence of this norm?

Tags: topological-groups, local-field

I am reading an [article](http://docdro.id/11a73) that states:

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a fixed local field. Then there is an integer $q=p^r$, where p is a fixed prime element of $\mathbb{K}$ and r is a positive integer, and a norm $\left | . \right |$ on $\mathbb{K}$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{K}$ we have $\left | x \right |\geq 0$ and for each $x\in \mathbb{K}$(except 0) we get $\left | x \right |=q^k$ for some integer k. This norm is non-Archimedean, that is $\left | x+y \right |\leq max\left \{ \left | x \right |,\left | y \right | \right \}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{K}$ and $\left | x+y \right |=max\left \{ \left | x \right |,\left | y \right | \right \}$ whenever $\left | x \right |\neq \left | y \right |$.

how do i prove the existence of this norm?

and

how to prove that the norm is non-Archimedean?

Comment: What is the best book or refrence for this topic?

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311527/is-there-such-a-norm-on-any-totally-disconnected-local-field).